# Strong way to identify user without signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, cookies

I'm building a Rails app where users can report pollutions on a map. It's free and open source, and I don't want people to give me their email, facebook account, or any personal information to use it. So I don't have a `User` model BUT I do need to identify people.

I have a `Report` model which a single user can only create once in 24 hours. If I had a user model referenced in it I would validate it like this:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validate :only_once_per_user_per_day

  def only_once_per_user_per_day
    if user.reports.where(created_at: (1.day.ago..created_at)
      errors.add(:created_at, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

For now I'm using cookies to give browsers a uniq id. So it looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def authenticate_user
    return if user_id

    @user_id = cookies[:user_id] = SecureRandom.uuid
  end

  def user_id
    @user_id ||= cookies[:user_id]
  end
end
```

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  validate :only_once_per_user_per_day

  def only_once_per_user_per_day
    if reports.where(user_id: user_id, created_at: (1.day.ago..created_at)
      errors.add(:created_at, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

I know it's not perfect, a single user can come back in private mode, clear cookies or change browser to report again in the same day.

Do you know a stronger way than using cookies to identify user/browser without sign up? It doesn't have to be perfect. I mean even with an auth system users could still create multiple accounts. I'm thinking about using request IP for example.

Comment: Where should I ask this if not on SO ?

Comment: This question could be edited to be on-topic for SO, but right now you have some undefined terms: "better" and "more secured". Better how? More secure against what form of attack/vulnerability? If there is a specific thing you want to protect against, edit the question to ask how to write your code to protect against that, specifically.

Comment: @TylerH thank you for this answer, I edited my post.

Comment: That's a great improvement; I removed my close vote. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer two options, but finding the perfect one in this case is difficult.

[FingerprintJS](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) and [Authenticate with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

*Restricting on IP only for example might cause problems with mobile providers who use one IP for many devices.*

Comment: I love the FPJS approach, think I'll go with it.